# Linux socket- they disconnected or we did?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I am receiving bytes through `::recv()` and have a scenario where it returns zero. According to here:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_system_calls/recv.htm

this means:

> The return value will be 0 when the peer has performed an orderly
>   shutdown.

Is there any way to find out which side of the connection closed it? I do not know whether the remote client killed our connection, or some logic on our side closed it.

Comment: `::recv` is not C, but possibly C++. Use the correct language tag. But there are other reason to get `0`, e.g. for a non-blocking socket.

Comment: I'm fairly certain ::recv() is in C because its part of glibc (http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Receiving-Data.html) and the Linux kernel is written in C? I don't think I'm using non-blocking socket.

Comment: @Olaf I also think that a C tag is justified.

Comment: @user997112: Hoiw is the Linux Kernel related? And also Python is written in C and uses e.g. the Linux kernel. Does that make any Python question C related? Maybe we should add machine language tags, too because all code ist finally executed by the CPU.

Comment: @Olaf: "*... for a non-blocking socket*" `rev()` returning `0` definitely means that the other side performed an orderly shutdown. If no data is around a non-blocking socket would return `-1` setting `errno` to  `EWOULDBLOCK`/`EAGAIN`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to find out which side of the connection closed it?

The peer closed it. The other side.

> I do not know whether the remote client killed our connection, or some logic on our side closed it.

Yes you do. The peer closed it. If you had closed it you would get an error `EBADF`.